# T-SQL - sp_OAGetProperty Error: The source data specified for this string or binary column or parameter is too long

Tags: sql-server, web-services, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have built a stored procedure to call a web service and retrieve a response from the endpoint. Everything works great, except for some exceptions. I am using `sp_OACreate`, `sp_OAMethod` and `sp_OAGetProperty` to request and get responses back. I have tested 686 times all with different data, 9 of which are failing with this error:

> Response Failed on  Object ID: ODSOLE Extended Procedure. Description: The source data specified for this string or binary column or parameter is too long

I also have a status text response of:

> For input string: " D" "`and a status of "`400`

According to my logs, my request "Send" is succeeding and the message is getting received successfully. Its the response that's not getting back successfully.

Whats weird is I contacted folks on the responding side of my request and they are sending back a message that I have received successfully from other requests, below:

```
<responses success="true">
     <response key="quoteRequest" service="quoteRequest" success="false" 
               message="Processing error received for quote request. Support has been notified and is looking into the error.">
    </response>
</responses>
```

I know the max length is 4000 for this SQL function, and responses will never get that long, even if the request is successful.

Here is the SQL I am using to execute. I would include the URL, but I feel that the responding company wouldn't like that...:

```
DECLARE
    --this message is successful                                            
    @in_vchXMLMessage NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><requests username="WENG02importcreate" password="" id="69" token="db0bb761-88ea-11e7-95ef-0050560903bc"><request service="quoteRequest"><QuoteRequest><Header><Action>Add</Action><Date type="generation">2017-08-25T14:09:06.360</Date></Header><Shipment><Status>Pending</Status><Enterprise customerAcctNum="DSI-142319-110469" name="CHRIS STORJOHANN"/><ReferenceNumbers><ReferenceNumber type="Quote Number" isPrimary="true">1630178.000000000*</ReferenceNumber></ReferenceNumbers><Comments><Comment/></Comments><EquipmentList><EquipmentCode desc="" qty=""/></EquipmentList><Dates><Pickup><Date type="earliest">2017/08/14 00:00</Date><Date type="latest">2017/08/14 00:00</Date></Pickup><Drop><Date type="earliest">2017/08/14 00:00</Date><Date type="latest">2017/08/14 00:00</Date></Drop></Dates><Shipper><Address isResidential="false"><Alias/><Name>WENGER CORPORATION</Name><AddrLine1>555 PARK DRIVE</AddrLine1><City>OWATONNA</City><StateProvince>MN</StateProvince><PostalCode>55060</PostalCode><CountryCode>USA</CountryCode><Contacts><Contact><Name/><ContactMethods><ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""/></ContactMethods></Contact></Contacts><Comments/></Address></Shipper><Consignee><Address isResidential="false"><Alias/><Name>Tufts University</Name><AddrLine1>20 Talbot Ave</AddrLine1><City>Medford</City><StateProvince>MA</StateProvince><PostalCode>02155-5813</PostalCode><CountryCode>USA</CountryCode><Contacts><Contact><Name/><ContactMethods><ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""/></ContactMethods></Contact></Contacts><Comments/></Address></Consignee><HandlingUnits><HandlingUnit stackable="false" sequence="1"><Quantity units="Pallet">7.0</Quantity><Weight units="lb">147.0</Weight><Dimensions height="14.0" units="in" width="21.0" length="85.0"/><Items><Item sequence="1"><Description>RISER,3 STEP,6-18,GREY/GREY</Description><FreightClass>085</FreightClass><HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial><Weights><Weight units="lbs" type="planned">147.0</Weight></Weights><Quantities><Quantity type="planned">7.0</Quantity></Quantities><MonetaryValue units="USD">0.0</MonetaryValue></Item></Items></HandlingUnit></HandlingUnits><Payment><Method>Third Party</Method><BillTo thirdParty="true"><Address isresidential="false"><Alias/><Name>Diversified</Name><AddrLine1>37 Market St</AddrLine1><City>Kenilworth</City><StateProvince>NJ</StateProvince><PostalCode>07033</PostalCode><Contacts><Contact><Name/><ContactMethods><ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""/></ContactMethods></Contact></Contacts></Address></BillTo></Payment></Shipment></QuoteRequest></request></requests>',

    -- this message is unsuccessful
    -- @in_vchXMLMessage NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><requests username="WENG02importcreate" password="" id="69" token="db0bb761-88ea-11e7-95ef-0050560903bc"><request service="quoteRequest"><QuoteRequest><Header><Action>Add</Action><Date type="generation">2017-08-28T10:20:27.767</Date></Header><Shipment><Status>Pending</Status><Enterprise customerAcctNum="CK COMING- 100% DOWN" name="SHERRY ROOT"/><ReferenceNumbers><ReferenceNumber type="Quote Number" isPrimary="true">1633560.3910</ReferenceNumber></ReferenceNumbers><Comments><Comment/></Comments><EquipmentList><EquipmentCode desc="" qty=""/></EquipmentList><Dates><Pickup><Date type="earliest">2017/08/21 00:00</Date><Date type="latest">2017/08/21 00:00</Date></Pickup><Drop><Date type="earliest">2017/08/21 00:00</Date><Date type="latest">2017/08/21 00:00</Date></Drop></Dates><Shipper><Address isResidential="false"><Alias/><Name>WENGER CORPORATION</Name><AddrLine1>555 PARK DRIVE</AddrLine1><City>OWATONNA</City><StateProvince>MN</StateProvince><PostalCode>55060</PostalCode><CountryCode>USA</CountryCode><Contacts><Contact><Name/><ContactMethods><ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""/></ContactMethods></Contact></Contacts><Comments/></Address></Shipper><Consignee><Address isResidential="false"><Alias/><Name>Russell Elementary School</Name><AddrLine1>195 School St</AddrLine1><City>Rumney</City><StateProvince>NH</StateProvince><PostalCode>03266-3413</PostalCode><CountryCode>USA</CountryCode><Contacts><Contact><Name/><ContactMethods><ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""/></ContactMethods></Contact></Contacts><Comments/></Address></Consignee><HandlingUnits><HandlingUnit stackable="false" sequence="1"><Quantity units="Pallet">2.0</Quantity><Weight units="lb">1.0</Weight><Dimensions height="10.0" units="in" width="10.0" length="10.0"/><Items><Item sequence="1"><Description>RISER,SIGNATURE,3 STEP</Description><FreightClass>065</FreightClass><HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial><Weights><Weight units="lbs" type="planned">1.0</Weight></Weights><Quantities><Quantity type="planned">2.0</Quantity></Quantities><MonetaryValue units="USD">0.0</MonetaryValue></Item></Items></HandlingUnit><HandlingUnit stackable="false" sequence="1"><Quantity units="Pallet">2.0</Quantity><Weight units="lb">129.0</Weight><Dimensions height="105.0" units="in" width="186.0" length="725.0"/><Items><Item sequence="1"><Description>STEP/BACKRAIL PACK,3 STEP</Description><FreightClass>065</FreightClass><HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial><Weights><Weight units="lbs" type="planned">129.0</Weight></Weights><Quantities><Quantity type="planned">2.0</Quantity></Quantities><MonetaryValue units="USD">0.0</MonetaryValue></Item></Items></HandlingUnit><HandlingUnit stackable="false" sequence="1"><Quantity units="Pallet">2.0</Quantity><Weight units="lb">98.0</Weight><Dimensions height="95.0" units="in" width="330.0" length="485.0"/><Items><Item sequence="1"><Description>CARRIAGE/STRINGER PK,3 STEP</Description><FreightClass>065</FreightClass><HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial><Weights><Weight units="lbs" type="planned">98.0</Weight></Weights><Quantities><Quantity type="planned">2.0</Quantity></Quantities><MonetaryValue units="USD">0.0</MonetaryValue></Item></Items></HandlingUnit></HandlingUnits><Payment><Method>Third Party</Method><BillTo thirdParty="true"><Address isresidential="false"><Alias/><Name>Russell Elementary School</Name><AddrLine1>195 School St</AddrLine1><City>Rumney</City><StateProvince>NH</StateProvince><PostalCode>03266-3413</PostalCode><Contacts><Contact><Name/><ContactMethods><ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""/></ContactMethods></Contact></Contacts></Address></BillTo></Payment></Shipment></QuoteRequest></request></requests>',

-- Error handling variables
@v_nSysErrorNum             INTEGER,
@v_nRowCount                INTEGER,
@v_nReturn                  INTEGER,
@v_vchCode                  NVARCHAR(20),
@v_vchMsg                   NVARCHAR(200),
@c_vchObjName               NVARCHAR(50),

-- Local Variables
@v_nCount                   INTEGER,
@v_nObject                  INTEGER,
@v_vchURL                   NVARCHAR(2000),
@v_vchHost                  NVARCHAR(100),
@v_vchUser                  NVARCHAR(100),
@v_vchPswrd                 NVARCHAR(100),
@v_nResult                  INTEGER,
@v_vchSource                NVARCHAR(500),
@v_vchDesc                  NVARCHAR(500),
@v_vchStatusText            NVARCHAR(1000),
@v_vchStatus                NVARCHAR(1000),
@v_vchResponseXML           NVARCHAR(2000)

-- Set Constants
SET @c_vchObjName = N'usp_web_service_call';
SET @v_vchCode = N'SUCCESS';
SET @v_vchMsg  = N'NONE';

SELECT @v_vchURL = c1
FROM t_control
WHERE control_type = 'TMS_WEB_SERV_URL'

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                          Create Web Service Call
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXEC @v_nResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @v_nObject OUT

IF @v_nResult <> 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @v_nObject, @v_vchSource OUT, @v_vchDesc OUT
    SET @v_vchCode = N'-20001';
    SET @v_vchMsg = N'Create Failed on Object ID ' + ISNULL(@v_vchSource, '')  + ' description ' + ISNULL(@v_vchDesc , '');
    GOTO DESTROY; 
END

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                          Open Web Service Call
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXEC @v_nResult = sp_OAMethod @v_nObject, 'Open', NULL, 'POST', @v_vchURL, 'false'

IF @v_nResult <> 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @v_nObject, @v_vchSource OUT, @v_vchDesc OUT
    SET @v_vchCode = N'-20002';
    SET @v_vchMsg = N'Open Failed on  Object ID ' + ISNULL(@v_vchSource, '')  + ' description ' + ISNULL(@v_vchDesc , '');
    GOTO DESTROY; 
END

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                          Request Header Info
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXEC @v_nResult = sp_OAMethod @v_nObject, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

IF @v_nResult <> 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @v_nObject, @v_vchSource OUT, @v_vchDesc OUT
    SET @v_vchCode = N'-20003';
    SET @v_vchMsg = N'Header Failed on  Object ID ' + ISNULL(@v_vchSource, '')  + ' description ' + ISNULL(@v_vchDesc , '')
    GOTO DESTROY; 
END

SELECT 'req hdr', @v_nResult

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                      Send XML Web Service Message
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXEC @v_nResult = sp_OAMethod @v_nObject, 'Send', null, @in_vchXMLMessage 

IF @v_nResult <> 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @v_nObject, @v_vchSource OUT, @v_vchDesc OUT
    SET @v_vchCode = N'-20004';
    SET @v_vchMsg = N'Send Failed on  Object ID ' + ISNULL(@v_vchSource, '')  + ' description ' + ISNULL(@v_vchDesc , '')
    GOTO DESTROY; 
END

SELECT 'send xml', @v_nResult

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                              Get Status Text
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXEC @v_nResult = sp_OAGetProperty @v_nObject, 'StatusText', @v_vchStatusText OUT

IF @v_nResult <> 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @v_nObject, @v_vchSource OUT, @v_vchDesc OUT
    SET @v_vchCode = N'-20004';
    SET @v_vchMsg = N'Send Failed on  Object ID ' + ISNULL(@v_vchSource, '')  + ' description ' + ISNULL(@v_vchDesc , '')
    GOTO DESTROY; 
END

sELECT 'statustext', @v_vchStatusText

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                                  Get Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXEC @v_nResult = sp_OAGetProperty @v_nObject, 'Status', @v_vchStatus OUT

IF @v_nResult <> 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @v_nObject, @v_vchSource OUT, @v_vchDesc OUT
    SET @v_vchCode = N'-20004';
    SET @v_vchMsg = N'Send Failed on  Object ID ' + ISNULL(@v_vchSource, '')  + ' description ' + ISNULL(@v_vchDesc , '')
    GOTO DESTROY; 
END

sELECT 'status', @v_vchStatus

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--                              Get response text 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EXEC @v_nResult = sp_OAGetProperty @v_nObject, 'responseText', @v_vchResponseXML OUTPUT

sELECT @v_vchResponseXML

IF @v_nResult <> 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @v_nObject, @v_vchSource OUT, @v_vchDesc OUT
    SET @v_vchCode = N'-20005';
    SET @v_vchMsg = N'Response Failed on  Object ID: ' + ISNULL(@v_vchSource, '')  + '. Description: ' + ISNULL(@v_vchDesc , '')
    GOTO DESTROY; 
END

sELECT @v_vchResponseXML

DESTROY:
EXEC sp_OADestroy @v_nObject

SELECT @v_nObject, @v_vchCode, @v_vchMsg
```

UPDATE 10-26-2017:
Here is the string used in the web service send.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<requests username="WENG02importcreate" password="" id="69" token="db0bb761-88ea-11e7-95ef-0050560903bc">
   <request service="quoteRequest">
      <QuoteRequest>
         <Header>
            <Action>Add</Action>
            <Date type="generation">10/25/2017 15:29:54</Date>
         </Header>
         <Shipment>
            <Status>Pending</Status>
            <Enterprise customerAcctNum="WENG02EXT" name="WENGER CORPORATION EXECUTION" />
            <ReferenceNumbers>
               <ReferenceNumber type="ShipmentID" isPrimary="true">1638351.0000193682</ReferenceNumber>
               <ReferenceNumber type="OrderNumber" isPrimary="false">1638351</ReferenceNumber>
               <ReferenceNumber type="WengerInstall" isPrimary="false">false</ReferenceNumber>
               <ReferenceNumber type="Cube" isPrimary="false">105.4</ReferenceNumber>
               <ReferenceNumber type="Customer PO" isPrimary="false">50% CHECK RECEIVED #5104</ReferenceNumber>
               <ReferenceNumber type="ShipCondition" isPrimary="false">PPB</ReferenceNumber>
            </ReferenceNumbers>
            <Comments>
               <Comment type="SpecialInstructions" />
            </Comments>
            <Dates>
               <Pickup>
                  <Date type="earliest">11/06/2017 00:00</Date>
                  <Date type="latest">11/06/2017 00:00</Date>
               </Pickup>
               <Drop>
                  <Date type="earliest">11/06/2017 00:00</Date>
                  <Date type="latest">11/06/2017 00:00</Date>
               </Drop>
            </Dates>
            <Shipper>
               <Address isResidential="false">
                  <Alias />
                  <Name>WENGER CORPORATION</Name>
                  <AddrLine1>555 PARK DRIVE</AddrLine1>
                  <City>OWATONNA</City>
                  <StateProvince>MN</StateProvince>
                  <PostalCode>55060</PostalCode>
                  <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
                  <Contacts>
                     <Contact>
                        <Name />
                        <ContactMethods>
                           <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum="" />
                        </ContactMethods>
                     </Contact>
                  </Contacts>
                  <Comments>
                     <Comment>50% DOWNPAYMENT CHECK RECEIVED</Comment>
                  </Comments>
               </Address>
            </Shipper>
            <Consignee>
               <Address isResidential="false">
                  <Alias />
                  <Name>Immanuel Lutheran Church</Name>
                  <AddrLine1>N554 County Road R</AddrLine1>
                  <City>Watertown</City>
                  <StateProvince>WI</StateProvince>
                  <PostalCode>53098-4805</PostalCode>
                  <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
                  <Contacts>
                     <Contact>
                        <Name>Att: Lynn Baumann</Name>
                        <ContactMethods>
                           <ContactMethod type="phone" sequenceNum="1">920-925-3540</ContactMethod>
                        </ContactMethods>
                     </Contact>
                  </Contacts>
                  <Comments />
               </Address>
            </Consignee>
            <HandlingUnits>
               <HandlingUnit stackable="false" sequence="1">
                  <Quantity units="Pallet">9.0</Quantity>
                  <Weight units="lb">804.0</Weight>
                  <Dimensions height="23.0" units="in" width="143.0" length="257.0" />
                  <Items>
                     <Item sequence="1" id="024F017">
                        <Description>CLEACHERS OR GRANDSTANDS METAL OR WOOD, KD, TELESCOPED OR COLLAPSED, NOI; OR PARTS, NOI</Description>
                        <FreightClass>085</FreightClass>
                        <HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial>
                        <Weights>
                           <Weight units="lbs" type="planned">804.0</Weight>
                        </Weights>
                        <NMFC>89803</NMFC>
                        <Quantities>
                           <Quantity type="planned">9.0</Quantity>
                        </Quantities>
                        <MonetaryValue units="USD">0.0</MonetaryValue>
                     </Item>
                  </Items>
               </HandlingUnit>
            </HandlingUnits>
            <Payment>
               <Method>Prepaid</Method>
               <BillTo thirdParty="false">
                  <Address isresidential="false">
                     <Alias />
                     <Name>WENGER CORPORATION</Name>
                     <AddrLine1>PO BOX 23000</AddrLine1>
                     <AddrLine2 />
                     <City>Hickory</City>
                     <StateProvince>NC</StateProvince>
                     <PostalCode>28603</PostalCode>
                     <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
                     <Contacts>
                        <Contact>
                           <Name />
                           <ContactMethods>
                              <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum="" />
                           </ContactMethods>
                        </Contact>
                     </Contacts>
                  </Address>
               </BillTo>
            </Payment>
         </Shipment>
      </QuoteRequest>
   </request>
</requests>
```

Has anyone experienced this issue when the response is no where near the maximum length? Thanks for any help!

Comment: "The source data specified for this string or binary column or parameter is too long" and "I know the max length is 4000 for this SQL function" - why do you use `NVARCHAR(2000)` then? Have you tried increasing the size?

Comment: @Alex is right that if you initially assign your message to this variable `@in_vchXMLMessage NVARCHAR(MAX)` there is no reason to declare `@v_vchResponseXML` as `NVARCHAR(2000)` - this is potential conflict in case you don't process `@in_vchXMLMessage` somewhere to make sure that its length will definitly meet 2000 limit.

Comment: I updated the @v_vchResponseXML to NVARCHAR(MAX) and I am now getting a new error message: >Error in srv_convert. The status and status test remain the same.

Comment: Hi everyone. I am revisiting this issue because it doesn't seem that the length of the string is a problem. I have successfully sent strings that are over 4000 character long to its destination. But now I am sending strings that aren't nearly 4000 chars and they are failing the web service send using the above method in SQL. Here is the message from SQL: "Response Failed on Object ID ODSOLE Extended Procedure description The source data specified for this string or binary column or parameter is too long" The source data is 3260 char long. Issue is sporadic.. Refer to "UPDATE 10-26-2017" above.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the content length to web server.
In your code, this could be done as:

```sql
SET @len = LEN(@in_vchXMLMessage);
EXEC @v_nResult = sp_OAMethod @v_nObject,'setRequestHeader',NULL,'Content-Length',@len;
IF @v_nResult <> 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @v_nObject, @v_vchSource OUT, @v_vchDesc OUT
    SET @v_vchCode = N'-20004';
    SET @v_vchMsg = N'Lengh Failed on  Object ID ' + ISNULL(@v_vchSource, '')  + ' description ' + ISNULL(@v_vchDesc , '')
    GOTO DESTROY; 
END
SELECT 'set len', @v_nResult
```

you should do that before sending the main message.
Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

use table type to get an unlimited response in it.

replace lines in your code as below:

```
DECLARE @ResponseTable as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'ResponseText', @ResponseTable OUTPUT
INSERT into @ResponseTable(Json_Table) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'ResponseText'
SELECT * from @ResponseTable
```